# ReFS Block Cloning - Use command line to copy a file and use block cloning

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cloning, refs

The Resilient File System (ReFS) introduced block cloning, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/refs/block-cloning.

Let's assume I've a 128 GB ReFS partition and I've a 8 GB file.

If I copy and paste (duplicate) that file in the Windows Explorer on the above ReFS partition it look's like block cloning is not used. When only one file was on the disk the free space was around 120 GB. With twice the same file the free space was around 112 GB.

I observed the same behavior if use `copy` or `xcopy` in the command line.

So how could I use the block cloning feature of ReFS from the command line?

`fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo g:` returns

```
Volume Name : Test
Volume Serial Number : 0x960ecc56
Max Component Length : 255
File System Name : ReFS
Is ReadWrite
Not Thinly-Provisioned
Supports Case-sensitive filenames
Preserves Case of filenames
Supports Unicode in filenames
Preserves & Enforces ACL's
Supports Sparse files
Supports Reparse Points
Returns Handle Close Result Information
Supports Named Streams
Supports Open By FileID
Supports USN Journal
Supports Integrity Streams
Supports Block Cloning
Supports Sparse VDL
Supports File Ghosting
```

The final goal is to use `msbuild` and block cloning, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74234924/create-symbolic-link-instead-of-coping-the-content-to-the-output-directory

Comment: See http://blog.dewin.me/2017/02/under-hood-how-does-refs-block-cloning.html and https://github.com/tdewin/refs-fclone